# Screenoverlay is being offset in google maps in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, kml

I generate some KML that produces a screen overlay with an error message in the event that I have no location data for a given record. When it works, this looks like this:

[image: Working Example]

In one (consistent scenario) in firefox and chrome it does this instead:

[image: not-working example]

The difference between this and another page where this works in both Firefox and Chrome, is that the map container div is positioned on the left of the page it is not working on (using `position: absolute;`) and is set to: `float: right;` on the page in which is works.

The relevant section of KML to place this image is:

```
<ScreenOverlay>
  <Icon>
    <href>http://SomeURL.com/image.png</href>
  </Icon>
  <overlayXY x="0.5" xunits="fraction" y="0.5" yunits="fraction" />
  <screenXY x="0.5" xunits="fraction" y="0.5" yunits="fraction" />
  <size x="0" xunits="pixels" y="0" yunits="pixels" />
</ScreenOverlay>
```

Google map settings / initialization:

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(64, -117);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MapCanvas"), settings);
    var geoLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('@Model.KMLURL');
    geoLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

div on page in which this works:

```
div#MapCanvas {
 float: right;
 border: 2px solid #666666;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

div#MapContainer {
 float: right;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

div's on page where it does not work:

```
div#MapCanvas {
 border: 2px solid #666666;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

div#MapContainer {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

My best guess is this has something to do with how the divs are moved around as the page loads, which is somehow interacting with the placement of the image. I have tried the following:

1. Alternate placement code in the CSS, so no effect, even if it moves the map elsewhere the image is still offset on this page - making me think I may be way off track.
2. Unloading and reloading the KML layer manually using a javascript call once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the offending CSS setting: a div that wrapped the map container had this set:

```
text-align: center;
```

Which apparently will center the screen overlay with respect to the entire screen. If anyone has an explanation on why the CSS interacts with the screenoverlay at all I would love to know. Hope this helps someone else.

I corrected this with a `text-align: initial;` set on the CSS for the MapCanvas div.

Comment: Also of note, this only impacted the screenoverlay on Firefox and Chrome and not IE. Did not test Webkit.